# SQL: Group By cause with condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access table looking like this:

```
ID      Country       Application Date
--------------------------------
12      France        12/01/2016
12      Germany       01/01/2017
13      Germany       01/02/2017
14      Spain         23/01/2017
14      Germany       01/02/2017
15      
16      Greece        01/01/2017
```

I would like to get a single occurence of each ID with the most recent application date.

I tried this:

```
SELECT ID, Country, Max(Application Date)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID
```

But Access refused this query and wanted me to add the country in the group by clause, which can't work then. 
Moreover, I would like to be able to fetch the rows with no country and application date as well (like the row with ID=15).

The expected result would be:

```
ID      Country       Application Date
--------------------------------
12      Germany       01/01/2017
13      Germany       01/02/2017
14      Germany       01/02/2017
15      
16      Greece        01/01/2017
```

Comment: With that sample data, what's the expected result?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you may want

```
select t1.* from MyTable as t1 inner join
(
SELECT ID, Max(Application Date) as Application Date
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID
) as t2 on t1.Id=t2.ID and t1.Application Date=t2.Application Date
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this greatly helps! I realized that the number of rows of my table was incorrect and just noticed that there are some dulicate datas: (Same Id, same Country, same application date). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It works on your input data and returns correct output data. Try it, please )

```
SELECT d.id, MyTable.country, d.datemax
FROM (SELECT ID as id, Max(AppDate) as datemax
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID) as d 
,MyTable
WHERE d.id = MyTable.id and datemax = MyTable.appdate
OR (datemax is null and country is null)
```